# How can i change from promise to async/await

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, promise, google-drive-api

How I can change the arrow function in my code to async/await syntax in google  drive integration.

```
const listFiles = () => {
    setLoading(true)
    gapi.client.drive.files
        .list({
            pageSize: 500,
            fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType, modifiedTime)',
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            setLoading(false)
            const res = JSON.parse(response.body);
            setDocuments(res.files);

        });
};
```

the another one function I want to add async/await:

```
const initClient = () => {
    setLoading(true)

    gapi.client
      .init({
        apiKey: API_KEY,
        clientId: CLIENT_ID,
        discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
        scope: SCOPES,
      })
      .then(
        function () {
          setConnectStorage(true);
          gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);
          updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
          setLoading(false)
        },
        function (error) {
          alert(error)
        }
      );
  };
```

Comment: What is the current problem with this code? What is the issue with replacing this with `async` and `await`? Why don't you have a go at it?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const listFiles = () => {
  setLoading(true)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    gapi.client.drive.files
        .list({
            pageSize: 500,
            fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType, modifiedTime)',
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            setLoading(false)
            const res = JSON.parse(response.body);
            resolve(res.files)
        });
  })
};

const initClient = () => {
  setLoading(true)
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    gapi.client
      .init({
        apiKey: API_KEY,
        clientId: CLIENT_ID,
        discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
        scope: SCOPES,
      })
      .then(
        function () {
          setConnectStorage(true);
          // gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);
          // updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
          resolve({status: gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get()})
          setLoading(false)
        },
        function (error) {
          reject({status: false})
        }
      );
  })
};
```

Then run those functions:

```js
(async () => {
  const files = await listFiles()
  const status = await initClient()
})()
```